# Data generation mode video seeking

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, netstream, data-generation

I am building a Video Player and try to use data generation mode. But when I had tried to seek I could not find a way to properly proceed. I have searched a lot but could not find an example of seeking in data generation mode.

Can anybody help me in this situation please. If you have an example code for video streaming in actionscript-3 data generation mode please share. I need an example working code.

Answer (score 0):

does this help? http://forums.adobe.com/thread/646900

```
ns.seek(0);  //the parameter to seek() is irrelevant, as both the playout and FIFO buffers will be cleared

ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_SEEK);  //you can do this in NetStreamStatus if you want

ns.appendBytes(seekPosBytes);  //write the bytes to play from the desired stream position
```